# Remove Extra "Space" using List View and GridView

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

[image: The space I want to remove between list view items.]

So I am using a Grid View inside of a List View and when I run my application I get this weird spacing stuff before the row of my items, between the items, and at the end (can't see in picture), which I want to remove. Here is my XAML.

```
   <ListView x:Name="schemaTableListView"
              Width="600"
              Height="50"
              Margin="0,550,0,0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding phase}">
       <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Source Schema">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="300" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Source Table">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="300" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Does anyone know how to remove this? I tried setting the padding to 0 and several other things, but couldn't get it to go away. I bet it is something simple.

Comment: Have you tried `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`?

Comment: @KevinWallis No, but I just tried it and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole space?

Comment: The problem is that your `ContentPresenter` for the `ListViewItem`has a `Margin="6,0,6,0"`

Comment: @KevinWallis Yes, I am trying to remove all three spaces. You can't see it in the picture due to it being selected, but on the right side of the blue selected boxes there is a black line representing the edge of the boxes and I want it to align with the headers.

Comment: Can you give me some testdata, i want to try my solution

Comment: There really isn't any "test data." It's a list view that is editable (each column you can enter w/e since they are text boxes) and I don't have anything right at the moment that allows you to add more items to the list view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to set negativ `margin`

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.View>
        <GridView >
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Source Schema">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Width="300" Margin="-6,0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Source Table">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Width="300" Margin="-6,0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This works, I had to change mine to -5, is a scroll bar appearing at the bottom of yours?

Comment: Yes it also appears

Comment: Okay, I was wondering if the scroll bar on the side was adding to the length of the columns to a total width of 610 instead of the 600 Width I defined it and that it was offsetting it a little and the scroll bar at the bottom was appearing. Thanks for the help!